# Update Devise user field via jQuery partial form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I'm a real rails beginner trying to build a little app. So I got rails 4.2.5 and Devise for my User authentication. I've added two extra fields (username, city) to the user model. Everything works fine.

I got a partial at the top of my app, that is opened with jquery by clicking on a button on every page. This partial should include a input field, where the user can edit his city (via AJAX?). After submitting, the city should be changed and the page reloaded.

And now I'm not sure how to achieve this and what is the way to go. I just need a small guide that helps me to get this done! Because devise by default doesn't generate controllers and doesn't uses the normal paths, I'm a little bit lost with my small experience in rails.

Thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: Can you show the code you have for the partial so far? Is it shown only when a user is signed in? Also the code that is working fine - how do you update the username, city?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, big thanks to Hieu Pham! I figured out how to get it working with your steps. But I had to modify them a little bit, but now it's working :) So, here it is for everybody else who want to know:

**routes.rb**

```
devise_scope :user do
  patch "update/:id", to: "registrations#update_city", as: "update_city"
end
```

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def update_city
    @user = current_user
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {render inline: "location.reload();" }
      end
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Could not save client"
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:city)
  end

end
```

**my form partial**

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, url: update_city_path(@user), remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :city, placeholder: t('.yourcity') %>
  <%= f.button :submit, t('.submit') %>
<% end %>
```

Now it's working fine :) I know, i need to add better responds on save, but that was just for debugging!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions here, with or without customizing devise controller will work well:

**Solution #1: Customize devise controller**

1. Config route:

   **routes.rb**

   ```
   devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }

   devise_scope :user do
    post "/users/:id/update_city" => "registrations#update_city"
   end
   ```
2. Create according controller which inherit from devise controller:

   **app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb**

   ```
   class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
     def update_city
       # Do your stuff
       # return json here, if return javascript, go to step #3
     end
   end
   ```
3. In case return javascript, your view will be:

**app/views/registrations/update_city.js.erb**

```
    <!-- Your javascript here -->
```

**Solution #2: Create a new controller, don't care about devise**

1. Config route:

devise_scope :user do
  post "/users/:id/update_city" => "custom_registrations#update_city
end

2. Create according controller

   **app/controllers/custom_registrations_controller.rb**

   ```
   class CustomRegistrationsController < ApplicationController
     before_action :authenticate_user!

     def update_city
       # Do your stuff
       # return json here, if return javascript, go to step #3
     end
   end
   ```
3. In case return javascript, your view will be:

   **app/views/custom_registrations/update_city.js.erb**

   ```
   <!-- Your javascript here -->
   ```

2 solution is like the same, but different in how to customize devise, solution #2 don't touch devise default controller, but there will be 2 controllers related to updating user stuff. Depend on your system, these are just my suggestions! Welcome any comment.

Comment: What a great answer!! That's exactly what i needed to go further. I'll first try your second solution and then I'll give you feedback! Thanks again mate!

Comment: Hi @hieu-pham ! I tried your first solution. Now I'm getting the following error with my form:
`undefined method `user_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fcc97933af8>:0x007fcc91d6bd60>`
My form partial looks like this:
`<div class="citychange">
  <p>
    <%= simple_form_for @user, remote: true do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :city, placeholder: 'Deine Stadt' %>
      <%= f.button :submit %>
    <% end %>
  </p>
</div>`

Comment: Hey, just add url option to your form, it will be like `simple_form_for @user, remote: true, url: user_update_city_path(@user)`

Comment: Hey Hieu, thank you for your help! But now i get this error: `undefined method 'user_update_city_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fcc9555dd40>:0x007fcc95767280>`
My rake routes looks like this: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/hrmFDi2.png)